# Using JavaScript to inflate a blob?

Tags: javascript, compression, blob, inflate

I'm using a websocket to send a Jpeg image in blob form. I've compressed (gzipped) the blob but I'm unable to find a way to decompress it using JavaScript. Does anyone know how?

This is the code I'm using to read the blob and then convert it into a base64 string:

```
var r = new FileReader();

r.onload = function(){
    draw(btoa(r.result));
};
r.readAsBinaryString(e.data);
```

The `draw()` function basically draws the image using the base64 string, onto a HTML5 canvas.

I've found [this library](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate) to inflate strings, but it doesn't support blobs. (As far as I know / have tested) If anyone knows of a way, I would appriciate it. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a very similar thing for my [particle system editor](https://github.com/city41/particle.js), it has support for reading Cocos2D plist files. In the plist file is texture data, which is a png that has been compressed with gzip and then converted to base64. Here is how I do it:

```
var input = 'byu9g1RZpINUpVtoKoiKIqJYoris...'; // really long string

// from base64 to ascii binary string
var decodedAsString = atob(input);

// ascii string to bytes in gzipped format
var data = this._binaryStringToArray(decodedAsString);

// raw, uncompressed, binary image data into an array using gzip.js
var uncompressed = require('gzip-js').unzip(data);

// now take the raw uncompressed png and convert it
// back to base64 to use it as a data url
var asString = this._arrayToBinaryString(uncompressed);
var encodedForDataUrl = btoa(asString);

var img = new Image();
img.src = encodedForDataUrl;
```

I am using [gzip.js](https://github.com/beatgammit/gzip-js) to do the heavy lifting. You can see all this in action [here](http://city41.github.com/particle.js/exp/), you can get some plists to load into it [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/tree/master-v2/Resources/Particles). BoilingFoam.plist will work, just load it in the "Import/Export" section.

In the above code I call two methods, here they are:

```
 _binaryStringToArray: function(binaryString) {
        var data = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < binaryString.length; ++i) {
            data[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return data;
    },

    _arrayToBinaryString: function(array) {
        var str = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            str += String.fromCharCode(array[i]);
        }
        return str;
    },
```

The whole shebang is [here](https://github.com/city41/particle.js/blob/plist/public/javascripts/io/PlistImporter.js#L178)

Comment: Thanks! I see it uses require() so does that mean I'd need to use node.js?

Comment: It's using RequireJS, which is for the browser. gzip.js is challenging to get going. You might have some luck just grabbing my built version of it here: https://github.com/city41/particle.js/blob/plist/public/javascripts/third/gzip.js, then just do `requiregzip('gzip-js').unzip(...)` to use it.

Comment: Wow, this works really well! Thanks Matt. Wish I could give you more upvotes. :P Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped! It took me a bit to figure out the workflow, so happy to see it help others too.

Answer (score 1):

Get a byteArray and you can decode it using `pako`: http://jsfiddle.net/9yH7M/

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comment about why I am being downvoted.